# Comment est-ce qu'on dit "I've got you right where I want you"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Je suis en train de jouer un match de Scrabble en ligne, un match que je suis sûr de perdre.  Je voudrais dire, en plaisantant bien sûr, "I've got you right where I want you".

Google Translate m'a donne "Je t'ai juste là où je te veux", mais je ne sais pas si cette phrase donne une impression d’être facétieux en français comme en anglais.  Je n'essaie pas de le duper en lui faisant croire que je peux gagner -- j'essaye de faire une blague.

Comment: lI y a [plus fiable que google translate](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/I+got+you+where+I+want+you). Mais *I've got you right where I want you*. Le choix dépend de ce que tu impliques car *I've got you right where I want you* can imply different things... Are you sure you wanted to say you are losing?

Comment: @Laure Yes, in this case it's a 100% guarantee that I will lose by a good margin... I just want to make a joke.  I'm not trying to fool him.

Comment: @Haydentech que veux-tu dire par 'de façon faciale' ?

Comment: @mcadorel facetiously, as a joke

Comment: facetiously: en plaisantant

Comment: "I've got you right where I want you" veut dire: J'ai t'ai eu là oú je voulais. To get someone avoir quelqu'un.

Comment: @Lambie But is that really _to get someone_ or rather to set someone up in a certain way (here to pretend you've done so in a jocular way). The phrase is not _hey buddy, I gotcha!_. Also consider your translation using the past tense might be confusing and _avoir_ feels imprecise to me, you could be talking about finding a precise target (I hit you in the exact spot I wanted)...

Comment: @suiiurisesse There is another interpretation: Je te tiens lá oú je voulais. However, for a game, I would go with avoir quelqu'un. The tense is correct. It has to be made past in French though it is present tense in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je t'ai amené(e) exactement là où je veux.

Google Translate a mal interprété 'I've got you': ici c'est le *present perfect* de  *'get'*, et non l'idiome *'I **have got** (a car etc.)'*

Pour souligner la plaisanterie, on peut dire par antiphrase :

> Je t'ai amené(e) exactement là où je veux (ou pas)…
>
> C'est totalement ce que je voulais faire…

NB — "Je t'ai juste là où je te veux" est chargé d'une connotation salace évidente pour un francophone, je ne pense pas que tu veuilles dire ça à un(e) inconnu(e) :)

Comment: to get someone ne veut dire **amener**. C'est avoir quelqu'un, comme quand on dit: Et là, je t'ai eu. "He got me in that game.". "Il m'a eu lors du jeu".

Comment: So @Lambie, I take it that you disagree with the final sentence of the answer, where the poster says it will sound "inappropriate"

Comment: @Haydentech La réponse n'est pas bonne. Il y a une erreur de traduction. En tout cas, il est évident que si tu sais dire cette phrase-là en anglais, tu sais la traduire en français aussi.

Comment: Pour respecter le temps de la phrase j'utiliserais "voulais" plutôt que "veux". De plus le NB est selon moi faux, j'ai du mal à voir la moindre nuance salace dans cette phrase qui est juste une mauvaise traduction fort peu compréhensible.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre ce que tu voulais dire. Dis-tu cela pour bluffer (en sachant que tu vas perdre) ?

Est-ce que c'est dans le sens "Mener la danse" ?

De ce que j'ai compris, je pense que tu as voulu dire :

- Je t'ai amené là où je le voulais
- Je fais ce que je veux de toi

Comment: Je dirais plutôt « je t'ai *conduit/amené* » que *mené*. Mais effectivement le contexte donné dans la question est étrange et insuffisant.

Comment: En fait, j'ai employé le verbe "mener" pour faire référence à l'expression mener en bateau, mener la danse, mener par le bout du nez, ... Mais en effet, le fait d'employer "où" insinue logiquement une location, donc amener...  (édité)